# Why would Postman strip out the form post data?

Tags: http, postman

I got this Postman:

[image]

Obviously I've included the nickname field, but my Laravel app thinks otherwise. I clicked on the code link to get the curl version, and it returned this:

```
curl -X POST \
  http://192.168.1.143:8000/api/addresses/new \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: 507c0989-f02a-028c-4222-c91302402fd6' \
  -H 'accept: application/x.toters.v1+json' \
  -H 'accept-encoding: gzip' \
  -H 'authorization: Bearer {***obfuscated***}' \
  -H 'connection: Keep-Alive' \
  -H 'content-language: en-US' \
  -H 'content-length: 165' \
  -H 'host: 192.168.1.143:8000' \
  -H 'user-agent: Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 8.1.0; Pixel 2 XL Build/OPM1.171019.018)' \
  -d 'country_code=&street=&nickname=&lon=&phone_number=&is_default=&lat=&apartment=&building_ref='
```

Notice the params in `-d`, they're gone! How can I make Postman respect my params?

This made it work, by adding the values manually in curl:

> curl -X POST  http://192.168.1.143:8000/api/addresses/new  -H
>   'Cache-Control: no-cache'  -H 'Content-Type:
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded'  -H 'Postman-Token:
>   c04b38ca-c687-acfc-c4c7-b54bd85a6018'  -H 'accept:
>   application/x.toters.v1+json'  -H 'accept-encoding: gzip'  -H
>   'authorization: Bearer
>   {eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjEwMiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cDpcL1wvMTkyLjE2OC4xLjE0Mzo4MDAwXC9hcGlcL3VzZXJzXC9sb2dpbiIsImlhdCI6MTUyMDUxMjcxMSwiZXhwIjoxNjE1MTIwNzExLCJuYmYiOjE1MjA1MTI3MTEsImp0aSI6IkhzODRaamdjbnJEdlQ5Z3UifQ.TrFOeB5qKJ9DwWCqjDLSXXlBscBZKTtbogjWY_bLjdQ}'
>   -H 'connection: Keep-Alive' -H 'content-language: en-US'  -H 'host: 192.168.1.143:8000'  -H 'user-agent: Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 8.1.0; Pixel 2 XL Build/OPM1.171019.018)'  -d “country_code=657&street=toters&nickname=toters_office&lon=35.5243772&lat=33.8967797&phone_number=96176447024&is_default=1&apartment=toters&building_ref=toters”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the latest version on the Native app (v6.0.9) and copied your POST body data - When I selected the `code` option, I got the correct response:

[image: Postman]

[image: Postman]

Not really sure what the problem is that you're seeing there.

Comment: Is this on windows ?

Comment: Mine is yes, maybe that's the difference on your OS?

Comment: We got the same result on linux as well. mine is osx

Comment: we updated to the same version you mentioned.. yeah it worked even on mac! :)